# Make method public in sub class

Tags: typescript

I have a base class, which has a protected method foo and a child class, which wants to allow public access to foo. As this method will be called very often, saving an unnecessary function call would be great. Is there a "better" solution to achieve this? My current hack:

```
abstract class A {
  protected foo(X:T) {...}
}
class B extends A {
  foo(X:T) {super.foo(X);}
}
B.prototype.foo = (<any>A.prototype).foo;
```

Making foo public in A is not an option, as all other sub classes of A shall access foo only internally. Only the special child B shall allow access to foo from outside.

Comment: the simplest way would be to just use the super call as you have done and let the virtual machine worry about the performance. :)

Comment: Is renaming the method in the sub-class an option?

Comment: @toskv Stating "doing this (without changing prototype) will not have any performance implications" is a valid answer to this question - if its right.

Comment: @Saravana Renaming does not solve the issue, that there is an additional function call. It's not about not being able to write it, but about having an additional function call.

Comment: @Alfi You can do `class B extends A {
   foo2 = super.foo
}` without an additional call. But as @toskv mentioned if you are worried about the performance implications of another method call, you should probably be writing in assembly :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case the performance impact of an additional call should be small enough to ignore or just left to the virtual machine to optimize.

Making the method public in the child class is more explicit.